# How to make ReadTheDocs build graphs using graphviz

Tags: graphviz, read-the-docs

I have configured automated documentation building on https://readthedocs.org/ portal.
I am using [sphinx.ext.autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) extension which builds graphs using [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/).

I am not sure how to configure `.readthedocs.yaml` file to have graphviz installed before the build. So I do have graphs properly built with no warning:

```
generating indices... WARNING: dot command 'dot' cannot be run (needed for graphviz output), check the graphviz_dot setting
```

I tried:

- this:

```
build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: "3.11"
  jobs:
    pre_install:
      - sudo apg-get update
      - sudo apg-get install graphviz
```

then I see error: `/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found`

- and this:

```
build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: "3.11"
  jobs:
    pre_install:
      - apg-get update
      - apg-get install graphviz
```

then I see an error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Comment: you can try to add something like `whoami` as pre_install step to find out as what user the steps are executed, maybe that helps a bit. But if you are not privileged to install packages, you might have to generate the images somewhere else before you trigger the readthedocs build

Comment: I called `whoami` and the user is named `docs`.
Building images outside will be super problematic (in fact, it would be easier to build everything). I am sure other users faced the same problem, so there has to be other solution, especially as I am pretty sure that graphviz was available before as the same build was passing 5 months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got an answer from ReadTheDocs support, so there are changes to `.readthedocs.yaml` file structure and apps can be installed by specifying in `build.apt_packages` section. Documentation: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#build-apt-packages

So the proper config would look like this:

```
build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: "3.11"
  apt_packages:
    - graphviz
```

Comment: I have tested it and it works